# Google Cloud Platform instances: Unstable network bandwidths with long-distance connections

Tags: linux, linux-networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, wide-area-network

I'm trying to deploy a data processing system over a wide area covering multiple regions of GCP. Before doing this, I've been profiling the network connections over the variety of distances, but I've been experiencing frequent sudden drops in the bandwidth over long-distance networks. I'm wondering what would be the root cause of the issue?

The cluster is set up with e2-standard-4 (4 vCPU, 16GB memory) instances on five regions: us-west1-b, us-east1-b, us-central1-a, europe-west1-b, asia-east1-b. Below is a screenshot of the different bandwidths, and we're seeing the most bandwidth drops between the regions us-west1-b and asia-east1-b.

Any insights would be welcome!

[Bandwidths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAcGV.png)

Comment: @ArdenSmith I've specified the GCE specs in the content! They're consisted of 5 instances of  e2-standard-4 (4 vCPU, 16GB memory), distributed around different regions

Comment: I m pretty sure the problem is about the GCE are so small to handle the dataflow

Comment: @ArdenSmith I'm using qperf to measure the bandwidth and latency. Do you think that the tool is generating too much data compared to the GCE size?

Comment: I guess so. This is my theory. You can create another GCE with more high performance and test again and compare the result.

Comment: 1) That are many factors that can cause those **blips** in your performance graph that your application be designed to handle. The questions are a) does it matter and b) what performance does your application require? 2) Your instance is on the small end of VM instances with performance similar to a small inexpensive laptop. If your goal is to measure sustained traffic create much larger instances. In the real world CPU, Memory and Disk IOPS are usually the most important metrics for performance. Having a huge water pipe (network) is not useful if you can only fill up a bucket (your small VM).